# Finite and Infinite Cardinality Representation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let X be a set. Show that the cardinality of the set of finite sequences with elements from X has cardinlity $\aleph_o$ if X is finite and cardinality $|X|$ if X is infinite.

I was given the hint that this set can be written as $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}X$

I didn't realize $|X|$ and $\aleph_o$ have different meanings.

Comment: Not every infinite set has cardinality $\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Recall that the set of sequences of length $n$ is $X^n$, and the set of finite sequences is $\bigcup X^n$. If $X$ is finite then $X^n$ is finite, and its cardinality is strictly increasing; if $X$ is infinite use the fact that $|X\times X|=|X|$.

Conclude by using the fact that $|\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X^n|=\aleph_0\cdot\sup\{|X|^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$.